# Google Sheets RegEx: setting numerical ranges while not allowing letters

Tags: regex, google-forms

I'm using Google Sheet's response validation via Regex for a clothing order form. Unfortunately, my respondents don't read the instructions, and frequently include letters after their sizes (eg. '85inches').

Here is an example of one field, restricted to numbers from 84 to 130.

```
(8[4-9]|9[0-9]|1[0-2][0-9]|130)
```

How do I prevent the end users from being able to submit '90mm' instead of '90', so I don't have to spend ages cleaning up the responses?

I tried the following, but it did not seem to work properly and I couldn't actually submit anything for the field:

```
\^(8[4-9]|9[0-9]|1[0-2][0-9]|130)*$\
```

Thanks! It's a shame Google Forms only allows you to set a Maximum or Minimum value for a numerical response, but not both at once...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you pretty much have it. This should do the trick?

```
^(8[4-9]|9[0-9]|1[0-2][0-9]|130)$
```

Comment: D'oh! Guess I need to hit the books some more. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped. To be honest, you'd already done the difficult part!